# An improper integral question using residues theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Hi everybody can someone help me please??

$\int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {1-\cos \left( x \right) }{{x}^{2}}}
\,{\rm d}x$

I did this by myself:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Integrate by parts with $u=1-\cos(x)$ and $v=-\frac{1}{x}$.  Then, we have

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx \tag 1$$

Can you finish?

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the full solution

> We can write the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx =\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$$Next, we move to the complex plane and analyze the closed contour integral $I$ given by $$\begin{align}I&=\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{z}\,dz\\\\ &=\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^R\frac{e^{ix}}{x}\,dx\\\\&+\int_\pi^0 \frac{e^{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}}{\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi+\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iR e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi \tag 2\end{align}$$   As $R\to \infty$ the last integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approaches zero.  As $\epsilon \to 0^+$ the third integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approaches $-i\pi$.  Finally, the sum of the first and second integrals approaches $i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$.  From Cauchy's Integral Theorem, the value of the closed contour integral is $0$.  Therefore, we find that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=\pi$ and $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: I understand this but what about with $\dfrac{(1-\cos(x))}{x}|^{\infty}_{0}$?? how to evalue it??

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Note that $1-\cos(x)=O(x^2)$.

Comment: why this integer "$\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iR e^{i\phi}}}{R e^{i\phi}}\,iR e^{i\phi}\,d\phi$" goes to zero when R approach infinity?

Comment: @zackni The integral goes to zero as $R \to \infty$ since the integrand is, in magnitude, $e^{-R\sin(\phi)}$.  Then note that $\sin(\phi)\ge 2\phi/\pi$ for $0\le \phi \le \pi/2$ (with a similar bound for $\pi/2 \le \phi \le \pi$).